# Calculating the covariance of effect sizes for multiple-treatment multiple-enpoint studies

Tags: covariance, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm interested in finding the covariance of effect sizes for multiple-treatment multiple-outcome design given the scenario below.

Gleser and Olkin (2009) provided the formula for the estimating the sampling covariance between effect sizes for multiple-treatment (MT) studies as:

```
Cov(dt1,dt2)= 1/nc + dt1*dt2/2N
```

They also provided the formula for estimating the sampling covariance between effect sizes for multiple-endpoint (ME) studies as:

```
Covjj* = [(nt + nc)/(nt*nc)]pjj* + [(d1*d2)/(2*(nt+nc))]*pjj*^2
```

So in a scenario where we have two treatment groups and two outcomes (from which to calculate the effect sizes) as shown below:

```
Treatment Group 1(T1)        Treatment Group 2(T2)
Outcome 1(O1)                Outcome 2 (O2)
```

Using the covariance formula for MT, one can calculate the covariance between the effect size estimates for Outcome 1 for T1 and T2, or the covariance of the effect size estimates for Outcome 2 for T1 and T2.

Also, using the covariance formula for MO, one can also calculate the covariance of effect size estimates for Outcome 1 and Outcome 2 for each treatment ( T1 or T2).

So my question is: What formula do we use to calculate the covariance of effect size estimates:

a) For Outcome 1 for T1 and Outcome 2 for T2, and b) For Outcome 2 for T1 and Outcome 1 for T2?

This question was posted earlier in the thread:

[Calculating effect sizes and standard errors for the difference between two standardized mean differences](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/calculating-effect-sizes-and-standard-errors-for-the-difference-between-two-stan)

Any help is really appreciated.

Malakas